# How to start another main form in c#

Tags: c#, forms

At first, I show a login form. When a user enters the correct id and password, I want to show another form, and close the login form. Following is the way I start the login form.

```
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new FrmLogin());
    }
}
```

Now, when I want to show the main form, I call the `dispose()` method of the `FrmLogin` class, but the application ends immediately. My solution is changing the `visible` property of `FrmLogin` class into `false` and I know it is not right, please suggest a way for this to work out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can show login form as dialog and if login success then you can run main form as:

```
static class Program
{
     public static bool isValid = false;
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        using (FrmLogin login = new FrmLogin())
        { 
            login.ShowDialog(); 
            if (isValid)
            {           
                Application.Run(new MainForm());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

in your FrmLogin, validate user and set `DialogResult` as `Ok`. Here I did it on button click event.

```
private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    Program.isValid= true; // impliment this as method 
    if(Program.isValid)
    {
      this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
      // or this.Close();
    }
    else
    {
      //else part code
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you. it works. and i find a interesting thing that `loginform` class can be used as a dialog

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this approach with a static bool, it's not good design, and has several drawbacks. As I mentioned in my answer, the ShowDialog-method has a return value - it's the value of the property DialogResult when the Form is closed. By using this method you avoid unnecessary ties between the different objects.

Comment: @Onkelborg then how you send login status back to main? we can't send it as dialog result. agreed with you about static bool. but there should be a way to hold login status.

Comment: Why not the DialogResult? If you need to send other information, apart from "Login OK" or "Login Cancelled", use one or more public properties, pass a "Login Object" (maybe with a defined interface) etc. Tight coupling isn't good

Comment: this is beyond the scope of question

Comment: No, it's not. Using a static variable is a solution, but not a good solution. You have a working DialogResult, why not use it? Why introduce a static variable? It's more work to use that static variable..

Comment: login status need to check before showing second form. OP can yous whatever he preferred save login state, but question is not about how to keep login state.

Answer (score 2):

What about you make a second APplication.Run after the login has completed ;) Wait for it to close, perform login, then Application.Run for second form, which is the MAIN form.

Btw., "FrmLogin" is a violation of .NET naming patterns - you seem to be an old VB hand (it was a pattern from there). It should be LoginForm.

Comment: thank you, i'll try it.plus, i'm not a VB programmer. i use c++ more~~

Comment: this is how i write `this.Dispose();Application.Run(new MainForm());` but it still does not work

Comment: What side effects does it have to call run twice on the same application?

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar i have the same doubt

Comment: It works. I Do that quit a lot in my applications - first check login, set up connection, THEN start the application. All APplication.Run does is enter the message loop. Naturally you must know ho to properly declare and tear down forms. this.Dispose makes zero sense in a static main method to start with.

Comment: From MSDNTypically, 

The main function of an application calls this method and passes to it the main window of the application.

This method adds an event handler to the mainForm parameter for the Closed event. The event handler calls ExitThread to clean up the application.

Answer (score 2):

```
var loginForm = new LoginForm();
if(loginForm.ShowDialog() != dont_remember_see_intellisense_or_docs.OK)
  return;
var mainForm = new MainForm();
Application.Run(mainForm);
```

This will show the loginform as a dialog. In your loginform you have to set the return value to something appropriate (ie. OK) to show the mainform

Answer (score -2):

To show another form myForm from FrmLogin just simply call

```
myForm window = new window()
window.MDIparent = ParentForm;
window.Show();
```

Comment: Not the answer to this question